# Navigating through models using relationships with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I am working on a project where we have the following models:

- ItemType
- ItemSubtype
- Item

As an example I would say that:

**ItemType**: Hardware or Software

**ItemSubtype**: RAM, Power Supply (if Hardware) or Application, Operating System (if Software)

**Item**: 4GB DDR4 (if RAM) or MS Office 2019 (if Application)

These are the relationships I see:

1. An **ItemType** can have multiple **ItemSubtype** and **ItemSubtype** can only belong to one **ItemType**
2. An **ItemSubtype** can have multiple **Item** and an **Item** can only belong to only one **ItemSubtype**

[image]

These are my questions:

1. Obviously, an **Item** can only belong to one **ItemType**. Do I need to initiate a relationship between the **Item** and the **ItemType** models?
2. If question 1 returns true (this is the result of coding all day long!) what kind of relationship should I use? **ItemType** has many **Item** through **ItemSubtype** (hasManyThrough)? Or **ItemType** hasMany **Item** and **Item** belongsTo one **ItemType**? Or just use the **ItemSubtype** as an intermediate model and go from **Item** to **ItemType** via **ItemSubtype** and via versa without any direct relationship between **ItemType** and **Item**?
3. Do I need the **item_type_id** inside the **items** migration if I don't create a relationship between the **ItemType** and **Item** models?
4. Is there a different approach to this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ItemType has many Item through ItemSubtype`... does it though?  It seems like you have a item_type_id in the Item entity.  That would be a simple HasMany.

Comment: I see you ask about this in question 3.   Since we don't know the app requirements, it's pretty hard to answer some of these questions.  The only real question here is whether you need to discern the Items from the ItemType without processing the ItemSubtype and vice-versa.  If you are only discerning the items from the itemsubtype, then why would you need a relationship between items and itemtype?  That is a design decision and not something we can really answer.

Comment: @Devon clear! If I decide that I need to discern the Items from ItemType directly what should I choose? HasManyThrough and remove item_type_id from items migration OR keep it and use hasMany on ItemType?

Comment: That's up to you.  Database normalization would dictate the HasManyThrough, but Laravel doesn't have a BelongsToThrough relationship (the inverse), so if you decide you need that and don't want complex queries, you may want to denormalize and have the item_type_id in the items table.

Comment: @Devon Dude, your answers are spot on! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this :

```
dd($rental_obj->car->maker->make_name); // output : VolksWagen
```

if your Model has been good writed like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $id_renter
 * @property integer $id_car
 * @property float $price
 * @property Date $date_beg
 * @property Date $date_end
 * @property Car $car
 * @property Renter $renter
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 */
class Rental extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'integer';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['id_renter','id_car','price','date_beg','date_end'];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cars', 'id_car');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function renter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Renters', 'id_renter');
    }
}
```